# Placing components on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

Can i combine Java layouts in same JPanel. I'm stuck with with placing my components on JPanel. It shoudl be like this: JLabel, JButton, JButton , JLabel and new line and same. I used BorderLayout but it wont go to the next row, keep adding components to same row and I need a new row. Ideal sit[image: uation will be that i can use BorderLayout] combined with cardlayout or some other good solution.

EDIT: Solved with GridLayout (0,4) It will do the job till i learn to use GridBaglayout.  Thank you for trying to help me.

[image]

Comment: show your code and output.

Comment: My code is a mess now because of try and error. When I format it i will include code.

Comment: When you are ready to move onto GridBagLayout, have a look at my tutorial on how to use GridBagLayout : http://blue-walrus.com/2011/12/gridbaglayout-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can combine layouts.

Using a `JPanel` you are able to embed other `JPanels`:

```
JPanel back = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel rows = new JPabel(new GridLayout(3,3));

back.add(rows, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Without seeing your code though it's difficult to know exactly what you are trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can combine java layouts.

A common pattern I use is **BorderLayout** first on a frame. The central component expands out, while the other components shrink in. Inside these panels I might have a **Flowlayout** to show buttons evenly spaced horizontally on top.

Another common approach for forms is using a **Gridbaglayout**, then adding all the form elements at gridX and gridY positions. I then later can stretch and teak these cells using other constraints in the Gridbaglayout repetoire.

Can you add a screenshot so that we can see what you want to do?

Comment: Don't have enough reputation. I can add like this: [IMG]http://i44.tinypic.com/sxd5zl.png[/IMG]

Comment: Well first off you would be using a BorderLayout to start with. Next you have to decide how to arrange the components on the left or right. That all depends on what you want.